# Is it possible to express sigma-type in Martin-Löf type theory with other constructs

Tags: type-theory

In Martin-Löf type theory we have sigma types (dependent products). Is it possible to express them with other constructs? How expressive is dependently typed lambda calculus without them, i.e. what we can't describe without them?

Comment: So I can see that it's possible to define sigma types, however, it's impossible to define induction principle, but why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

We can completely express $\Sigma$ types in terms of $\Pi$ types in a way that's very reminiscent of Church encoding.  For any given universe $\mathscr{U}$ and any higher universe $\mathscr{U'}$, we may define $\Sigma$ as follows:

$$
\Sigma : \Pi_{A : \mathscr{U}} (A \to \mathscr{U}) \to \mathscr{U'}\\
\Sigma = \lambda A : \mathscr{U} .
         \lambda B : A \to \mathscr{U} .
         \Pi_{C : \mathscr{U}}
         (\Pi_{x : A} B(x) \to C) \to
         C
$$

(This is assuming implicit universe cumulativity, of course, but using explicit universe polymorphism instead doesn't change much anyway.)

The constructor $,$ and the projections $\mathrm{proj}_1$ and $\mathrm{proj}_2$ are similarly defined as follows:

$$
, : \Pi_{A : \mathscr{U}} \Pi_{B : A \to \mathscr{U}} \Pi_{x : A} B(x) \to \Sigma_{x' : A} B(x')\\
, = \lambda A : \mathscr{U} .
    \lambda B : A \to \mathscr{U} .
    \lambda x : A .
    \lambda y : B(x) .
    \lambda C : \mathscr{U} .
    \lambda f : \Pi_{x' : A} B(x') \to C .
    f(x)(y)\\
\mathrm{proj}_1 : \Pi_{A : \mathscr{U}} \Pi_{B : A \to \mathscr{U}} (\Sigma_{x : A} B(x)) \to A\\
\mathrm{proj}_1 = \lambda A : \mathscr{U} .
              \lambda B : A \to \mathscr{U} .
              \lambda v : \Sigma_{x : A} B(x) .
              v(A)(\lambda x : A . \lambda y : B(x) . x)\\
\mathrm{proj}_2 : \Pi_{A : \mathscr{U}} \Pi_{B : A \to \mathscr{U}} \Pi_{v : \Sigma_{x : A} B(x)} B(\mathrm{proj}_1(v))\\
\mathrm{proj}_2 = \lambda A : \mathscr{U} .
              \lambda B : A \to \mathscr{U} .
              \lambda v : \Sigma_{x : A} B(x) .
              v(B)(\lambda x : A . \lambda y : B(x) . y)
$$

The proofs that the expected introduction, elimination, and computation rules and uniqueness principle hold are left to the reader.  :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! `:)`

Comment: Does this suffer from the usual problem of Church encoding, namely that there is no induction principle?

Comment: @ZhenLin there *should* be an induction principle, but I'm having trouble defining it in Agda at the moment; let me get back to you on that :/

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, induction principle is the main problem. I wanted to ask this question, since most of dep. typed languages has W-types or similar constructs to define inductive types, I was wondering why this is necessary.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov I would guess it's because of totality; a Turing-complete system doesn't need $\rm{W}$ types, or $\rm{M}$ types for that matter, to define everything in existence.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame Are you sure that simply typed lambda calculus is turing complete? Turing machines might not terminate but all well typed DTLC programs terminate.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov It's known that the STLC is *not* Turing-complete; in fact, anything that is well-typed in STLC is well-typed in DTLC/CoC, but not necessarily the other way around.  I meant that something like *the partial extension of* MLTT, or partial System F, or the full version of my own informally-specified "System $\rho \kappa$", is Turing-complete, and so needs neither W-types nor M-types to create arbitrary tree-like structures.

Comment: This answer is either not correct or requires more explanation because $\mathrm{proj}_2$ is not well-typed. You apply $v$ to $B$ but $B$ is of type $A \to \mathscr{U}$ instead of $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: @Bob `v : Σ A B`. The definition of `Σ` is `\A B -> (C : Set) -> ((x : A) -> B x -> C) -> X`, therefore the type of `v` is actually `(C : Set) -> ((x : A) -> B x -> C) -> X`, so you can apply it to something of type `Set`. I rewrote it all in Agda syntax, I hope it makes the definitions easier to coprehend.

Comment: @kirelagin But `B` is not of type `Set`, or else you could not write `B x`.

Comment: @Bob Sorry, you are right. In order to define `proj2` we need an eliminator whose result type depends on the first component, but then we can’t write the definition of `Σ`.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame I don't see how turing completeness would allow the above definition of `proj2` to typecheck. You could inhabit the type but you would not get a projection with the correct computational behaviour. You still need dependent elimination in order to define sigma types in terms of dependent functions, turing completeness is not enough as far as I know.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to work in Agda; you want $v (B(\mathrm{proj}_1(v)))$, but then $y$ has the wrong type $B x$. This answer only has an encoding of existentials, not sigmas. We worked through an encoding with a friend, who wrote the following:
https://gist.github.com/mietek/d53a0e3aa52078969d9f0d74e1aad462#file-sigma-agda-L103-L105